# Hide or Delete a whole GridView row with specific text in the field

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

This is my first post here.

I have a simple ASP.NET query-string driven page with a GridView that lists contents of specific folders (based on the query-string).Some of these folders contain PDF's, which means on my windows file-server it creates a `thumbs.db` file (contains thumbnail images for folder views), unfortunately this file is listed in the GridView and it looks very unsightly, is there any  way I can alter the code of my GridView to delete or hide rows that contain `Thumbs.db` in the `Name` column.

**code behind (VB.NET)(shortened as there are a lot of folders)**:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles     Me.Load

    Dim Certs As New IO.DirectoryInfo("D:\PROCEDURES\Certs\")

Dim q As String
    q = Request.QueryString("type")

If q = "Certs" Then
        lbltype.Text = "Certs"
        GridView1.DataSource = Certs.GetFiles()
        GridView1.DataBind()
End If
End Sub
```

**ASPX code**:

```
asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
    CssClass="GridStyle" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="100%">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Document Name" SortExpression="Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl='<%#"http://intranet.(hidden).com/sqe/data/" + Request.QueryString("type") + "/" + Eval("Name")%>' Target="_blank" runat="server"><%#Eval("Name")%></asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Extension" HeaderText="Extension" SortExpression="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Length" HeaderText="File Size" SortExpression="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastAccessTime" HeaderText="Last Modified" SortExpression="Name" />
    </Columns>
```

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in Gridview_rowbound event

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
     HyperLink hl = (HyperLink) e.row.FindControl("HyperLink1");
       if (hl.Text == "Thumb.db")
       {
       e.Row.Visible=false;
       }
    }
}
```

porting to vb would be easy to you?

Comment: Hi, Many thanks for this. I converted it to VB.NET.

It didn't work at the start. But if you look at my Hyperlink i've put the #EVAL inbetween the tags, i simply moved the #EVAL to the Text Attribute of the Hyperlink tag and it worked :)

Thanks again!